# Google Viz Dashboard works with chart animation?

Tags: google-visualization

Does the **Google.Visualization.Dashboard** work with chart animation out-of-the-box? In my code below, I bound a `CategoryFilter` to an `AreaChart` and specified the animation options - the dashboard works fine but no animation when the data changes (by selecting new value via the control). Please let me know if I have missed something, the Google tutorial does not cover the [Dashboard nor the ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation) approach (which I'm using).

```
var control1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType' : 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId' : 'control1',
        'options' : {
            'filterColumnLabel' : 'ThisColumn',
            'ui' : {
                'labelStacking' : 'vertical',
                'allowTyping' : false,
                'allowMultiple' : false
            }
        }
    });

var areaChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType' : 'AreaChart',
    'containerId' : 'chart1',
    'options' : {
        'animation' : {
            'duration' : 4000
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Animation works. I don't know what kind of data you used so I set up one example with area chart but as a control used NumberRangeFilter.

See [demo at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/OjaTebO/1/edit).